# Почему не высвобождается ОЗУ после mysqldump?

Tags: mysql, debian

После mysqldump не высвобождается оперативная память. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть причина?

Запускаю команду вот так: `mysqldump --opt -uroot -ppass dbname| gzip > /backup/backup-`date +%d-%m-%y`.gz`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Простой ответ: потому что ей незачем.

Детальный ответ: есть две возможности. Либо mysqld во время дампа всё-таки заполнил shared buffers до предела, указанного в mysql.ini, либо операционная система во время активных операций ввода-вывода раздула буфера и кэши файловых систем и пока не сдувает их обратно за явным отсутствием надобности. И то, и другое по большому счёту значит, что машина вообще ничем не занята.

Comment: То есть всё в порядке и серверу не требуется моё внимание?

Comment: @ikerya наберите `free` например, увидите реально занятую  память. Специфика работы такова что без надобности память не высвобождается если  была чем либо занята. Сделано это для ускорения работы с файлами. Вот что пишут в интернетах по поводу сброса кэша . `# free && sync && echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches && free`  но вам навряд ли это надо.

Comment: @zalex понял. спасибо за ответ